# http verb to invoke services / methods

Tags: rest, web-services, http

what is the best practice in defining web service that represent a non REST command invocation?

For REST, basically we use POST to create new record(s), GET to retrieve record(s), PUT to update record(s) and DELETE to remove record(s). Which http verb should I use if I just want to invoke some other non resource function, for example - to flush a system cache?

Answer (score 0):

> Which http verb should I use if I just want to invoke some other non resource function, for example - to flush a system cache?

HTTP [request methods](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4) should be selected based on their alignment with their defined *semantics*.

The most important of these is to determine whether or not the semantics are [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1)

> Request methods are considered "safe" if their defined semantics are essentially read-only; i.e., the client does not request, and does not expect, any state change on the origin server as a result of applying a safe method to a target resource.  Likewise, reasonable use of a safe method is not expected to cause any harm, loss of property, or unusual burden on the origin server.

Advertising a safe link invites consumers to pre-fetch a link, or to crawl and index the representation found there.

If having Google and a billion of her closest friends flushing your system cache sounds expensive, then you probably don't want a safe method.

[PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) and [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) are unsafe methods with semantics of manipulating representations.  So if you had a schema that described a system cache, a client might PUT a representation of an empty cache in the entity body, and send that to you, whereupon you could flush the cache.  You could achieve a similar things with PATCH, sending a list of the edits needed to make the change.

Both of these rely on the illusion that your resources are just documents.  I GET a representation of your resource, I load that into my generic editor, make changes, send my edited representation back to you, and then it's up to you to manifest those changes (or not).

But they aren't required -- if you want to simply document that

```
PUT /df1645af-f960-4cc4-ad7a-d0ddd29903f8
Content-Length: 0
```

has the side effect of flushing the system cache, the REST Police aren't going to come after you just because you've introduced a bit of RPC into the mix.

Of course, if you were doing this with HTML, then your only choice would be [POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3).

> The POST method requests that the target resource process the representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's own specific semantics.

Which is to say, POST is always an option.

It's easy enough to imagine the flow -- you load up some bookmark, follow a system cache link, find a form with a flush cache button, and submit.  The browser would create the request as described in the form elements and submit it.

So *that's* going to be fine too.  And the REST police won't bother you for that, because that protocol is actually RESTful.

If those answers are unsatisfying, or if you are just surveying the space to know what options are available, you can review the [HTTP Method Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml).  To be honest, I've never found anything there I've wanted to use.  But if [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) is your jam....